# Tool for plotting a functional dependency matrix

Tags: windows, gratis, open-source, graphs, dependencies

I am looking for a free tool that is able to plot a [Design Structure Matrix (DSM)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Design_structure_matrix) of functional dependencies in a program. The output should be similar to the ones generated by [Ndepend](http://www.ndepend.com/docs/dependency-structure-matrix-dsm) or [cppdepend](http://www.cppdepend.com/Doc_Matrix). I have found tools that can generate dependency graphs, e.g. [Snakefood](http://furius.ca/snakefood/), but I'm unable to find free tools that can plot the dependencies in a matrix.

The tool should be:

- Free and open source
- Able to plot dependency matrices based on code
- Runs on Windows

The programming language is not important, but preferably not an obscure one.